# reading text from multiple table cells with same class names

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I need to scrape specific information out of a website. It's different people listed and the html looks like this for 1 person:

```html
<table class="novip">
        <tbody><tr class="novip">
          <td class="novip-portrait-picture" rowspan="5">
            <a class="novip-portrait-picture" href="###">
              <img class="novip-portrait-picture" src="/img/general/default/portrait/cat/default-portrait_m.jpg" alt="Noch kein Bild" onerror="portrait_m_image_failover(this)">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="novip-left">
            <a class="novip-firmen-name" href="###" target="_top">
              Dubler&nbsp;Martin
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="novip-right" rowspan="2">
            <a class="novip" href="/arzt/dubler-martin-bad-zurzach-5330-arzt.html">
              <img class="novip-right" src="/pictures/31814/web/small/31814.png">
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="novip">
          <td class="novip-left">
            <span class="novip-left-titel">
              Dr. med. 
            </span>
            <span class="novip-left-fachbezeichnung">
              Facharzt FMH für Allgemeinmedizin, Reiseme
              <a class="novip-left-fachbezeichnung" href="/arzt/dubler-martin-bad-zurzach-5330-arzt.html">
                ...
              </a>
            </span>
            <br>
            address...
            <br>
            Tel:&nbsp;056 249 27 77
            &nbsp;&nbsp; 
        </td></tr>       
      </tbody></table>
```

I need the text within the class `novip-firmen-name`, `novip-left-titel` and `novip-left-fachbezeichnung`.

I tried the following:

```
request('url', (error, response, html)=>{
if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    $('table .novip').each(function(i, value){

        var fullname = $(value).find('.novip-firmen-name').text();
        console.log(fullname);

        var link = $(value).find('.novip-firmen-name').attr('href');
        console.log(link);

        var title = $(value).find('.novip-left-titel').text();
        console.log(title);

        var fachbezeichnung = $(value).find('.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').text();
        console.log(fachbezeichnung);

        console.log('----------------------------------');

    }); 


}
else console.log("error");
});
```

it seems to work okayish, but sometimes it logs undefined for some reason. Also I feel like there is an easier way to just get the above listed information. I never worked with js and cheerio before so any help is appreciated. Thanks

PS: if you need the link to the website or more html, let me know.

Comment: If ".novip-firmen-name" class is coming once per table, you can directly get the elements with class name. and instead of using find every time just keep reference in a variable for 1 time and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because, for every table `td` it tries to find  `.novip-firmen-name` , `etc`. What you have to do is check if those elements exists in the table data, like this.

```
$('table .novip').each(function(){
  if($(this).find('.novip-firmen-name').length !== 0) {
    console.log($(this).find('.novip-firmen-name').text());
    console.log($(this).find('.novip-firmen-name').attr('href'));
  }

  if($(this).find('.novip-left-titel').length !== 0){
    console.log($(this).find('.novip-left-titel').text());
  }

  if($(this).find('.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').length !== 0){
    console.log($(this).find('.novip-left-fachbezeichnung').text());
  }

  console.log('----------------------------------');

});
```

Comment: this solves the undefined problem. It still does not get all the values properly. Meaning only once in the following format: name, link, title, fachbezeichnung and if one doesnt exist its empty. and then follows the "-----------------" and it repeats with the next entry. I am not sure why it doesnt work as intended tho. Link to the site: https://www.doktor.ch/aerzte/aerzte_k_ag.html